# How to install geoiplookup on CentOS 9 / Rocky 9 / Almalinux 9

Tags: geoip, rocky-linux, centos9

`geoiplookup` is no longer in yum. Supposed replacement `mmdblookup` is also not available.

How to install `geoiplookup` on CentOS 9 / Rocky 9 / Almalinux 9?

Comment: It is replaced by GeoIP and you can use this link for packages: https://pkgs.org/download/geoip